# Entity Framework Navigation Properties not loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm new to Entity Framework.  I'm using  the code first option. Below I have a basic model.  The database was created properly and the records persist properly but when I run the test method (defined after the model) a second time my header record loads fine, but my navigation property, Details, does not reload.  What am I doing wrong?

```
class Header
{
    public int HeaderId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Detail> Details { get; set; } = new List<Detail>();
}

class Detail
{
    public int DetailId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int HeaderId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("HeaderId")]
    public virtual Header Header { get; set; }
}

class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext() : base("EfTest")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Header> Headers { get; set; }
}

private static void DoIt()
{
    using (var ctx = new MyContext())
    {
        var hdr = (
            from header in ctx.Headers
            where header.Name == NAME
            select header).FirstOrDefault();
        if (hdr == null)
        {
            hdr = new Header();
            hdr.Name = NAME;
            ctx.Headers.Add(hdr);
            MessageBox.Show("Header not found; created.");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Header found!");
        }

        var det = hdr.Details.FirstOrDefault();
        if (det == null)
        {
            det = new Detail() { Name = "Hi" };
            hdr.Details.Add(det);
            MessageBox.Show("Detail not found; created.");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Detail found!");
        }

        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the **DetailId** primary key? If yes is it identity?

Comment: Yes, by code first conventions it's automatically a PK defined as an identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here Entity Framework use `Lazy-Loading`. In order to get details you should use `Eager-Loading`.You should use `Include` method in `System.Data.Entity` namespace to accomplish `Eager-Loading`.Change your query like the following.

```
       var hdr = (
                from header in ctx.Headers
                where header.Name == NAME
                select header).Include(h=>h.Details).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: In my real case I want to use the lazy loading though.  Shouldn't the detail record be loaded when I reference it?

Comment: Lazy loading only loads what you ask it to. You asked for the Header and you got the Header, if you also want the Detail you need to explicitly ask for Detail(using Include).

Comment: The point being that it doesn't load anything unnecessary or unasked for. Imagine having a table with 50 table references, but you only need the main one. Without lazy loading in this case that kind of query would take a long time to load.(For example you need to get a User, but you are not interested in that User's Orders. Lazy will not load the Orders since you didn't ask)

Comment: But I did ask for it. `var det = hdr.Details.FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Is there no way to ask to load sub-records later?

Comment: When you ask for it like that `var det = hdr.Details.FirstOrDefault()` actual database query is executed for getting details behind the scene. By the way if you use Entity Framework in web application it is useful to use Eager-Loading to avoid unnecessary server round-trip.

Comment: You can also use Load method. `ctx.Entry(hdr).Collection(d => d.Details).Load();`

Comment: I get that, and this is Windows, not web, there could potentially be a lot of unwanted data in my details, so I only want t load as needed,  I was under the impression that if I queried my original query that it would hit the database again and fetch the new records I was looking for, I'd be filtering some details out in my real case. Would I need to fully re-query the header and eagerly load the filtered details in that case?  That doesn't seem right, or very useful, so I'm thinking that I'm missing something.

Comment: The load method does seem to work better, but it there anyway to apply a filter?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't full understand :) what do you mean 'to apply a filter'?

Comment: I mean I only want to load a subset of the details.

Comment: Definitely. `ctx.Entry(hdr).Collection(h => h.Details).Query().Where(d => d.DetailId == 1).Load();`

Comment: Thank you.  That is what I was looking for.